# Why is the first frame timestamp 0.066667 and not 0?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, x264, ffprobe

I have a stream of TGA files created on disk and I programmaticaly build a h264  video using the x264vfw codec. Options CRT 23, medium preset, Fast Decode, keyint 30 (video is 60 fps), no cut scenes, yuv 4 2 0...

When i examine the video I notice the first (key)frame timestamp isn't 0, it's 0.066667.

Why is the first frame timestamp 0.066667 and not 0 ?

ffprobe command i use to extract the frame timestamps coupled with a bit of powershell magic to isolate the keyframes.

```
.\ffprobe.exe -select_streams v  -show_entries frame=key_frame,pkt_dts_time,pict_type -of csv .\new1.avi | ? { $_.split(",")[-1] -eq 'I' }
```

Output :

```
frame,1,0.066667,I
frame,1,0.566667,I
frame,1,1.066667,I
...
```

Comment: the human eye can see at about 1/16th of a second. its notable that your decimal value is equal to 1/15, or about the amount of time you would wait for the second frame.

Comment: You'll have to show your code. How many B-frames?

Comment: i use 2 b frames